# make value of one( key value pair )to be key of another in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel-5, keyvaluepair

i am  having a json response from which i wanted to create new json object

```
response = [
         {Detail:"Reuters ID",keyName:"Reuters_ID"},
         {Detail:"Parity One",keyName:"parity_one"},
         {Detail:"Parity level",keyName:"parity_level"}
        ];
```

i wanted to achieve this after manipulating keys and value pair

```
lang_Arr =[
      {Reuters_ID:"Reuters ID"},
      {parity_one:"Parity One"},
      {parity_level:"Parity level"}
     ];
```

i have tried doing it in two ways
   1) in this getting error as unexpected tokken (.)

```
    var Lang_arr =[];
    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) { 
     Lang_arr.push({value.keyName:value.Detail});

    });
```

2) here getting unxepected token [

```
 var Lang_arr =[];
    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) { 
     Lang_arr.push({value['keyName']:value['Detail']});

    });
```

i have tried assigning the values seperatly too but it doesn't work there also

```
    var Lang_arr=[];
        var k ='';
        var v ='';
        var i = 1;

    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) { 
        k ='';
        v ='';
        i = 1;
        angular.forEach(value,function(val,key){
            if(i == 1 )
                k = val;
            if(i == 2)
                v = val;

            if(!empty(k) && !empty(v))
                Lang_arr.push({k:v})



            i++;
        }); 

    });
```

Comment: exactly what you need. [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular **forEach** also you can achieve this functionality

```
var response = [
         {Detail:"Reuters ID",keyName:"Reuters_ID"},
         {Detail:"Parity One",keyName:"parity_one"},
         {Detail:"Parity level",keyName:"parity_level"}
        ];
        var modifiedArray = [];
      angular.forEach(response, function(val, key) {
        var res = {};
            res[val.keyName] = val.Detail;
        this.push(res);
        }, modifiedArray);  

console.log(modifiedArray)
```

[**Working Example in Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qdycucwc/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript `map` function to map the objects to array

```js
var response = [
         {Detail:"Reuters ID",keyName:"Reuters_ID"},
         {Detail:"Parity One",keyName:"parity_one"},
         {Detail:"Parity level",keyName:"parity_level"}
];
        
var lang_Arr =[];

lang_Arr = response.map(function(o){
  var obj = {};
  obj[o.Detail] = o.keyName;
  return obj;
  
})

console.log(lang_Arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it in the http call that gets the response

```
$htpp.get(....).then(function(response){
lang_arr = []; 
 response.forEach(function(obj){
    var item = {obj.keyName : obj.detail};
    lang_arr.push(item);
}
```

Comment: ive tried using it but it gives out the same error( Unexpected token .)